# Как вывести на странице Детали товара, отзывы о товаре в Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Требуется создать шаблон с якорями для товара.

Описание товара вывел так - `<?php the_content (); ?>`

Как вывести детали товара (атрибуты товара) и отзывы о товаре?

Woocommerce - 3.4.4. Тема - Flatsome

Comment: Возможность отставить отзыв и посмотреть отзывы вывел с помощью <?php comments_template(); ?>. Логично. Осталось вывести атрибуты.

Comment: попробуй этот плагин для вывода https://wordpress.org/plugins/rich-reviews/#description